# Static and dynamic binding ambiguity

Tags: java, binding

I have the following code:

```
class A{
    public void print(A a){
        System.out.println("A 1");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public void print(A a){
        System.out.println("B 1");
    }
    public void print(B b){
        System.out.println("B 2");
    }
}

class C extends B{
    public void print(A a){
        System.out.println("C 1");
    }
    public void print(B b){
        System.out.println("C 2");
    }
    public void print(C c){
        System.out.println("C 3");
    }
}

class D extends C{
    public void print(A a){
        System.out.println("D 1");
    }
    public void print(B b){
        System.out.println("D 2");
    }
    public void print(C c){
        System.out.println("D 3");
    }
    public void print(D d){
        System.out.println("D 4");
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        B inst = new C();
        inst.print(new D());
    }
}
```

The output is C 2, but i cannot understand why. Ok, i get it, a method from the C class will be called because of the dynamic binding. Now why does it choose the second method? Why doesn't it choose the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Since `inst` is declared as type `B`, the only methods visible are the ones visible to `B`

```
class B extends A{
    // @Override
    public void print(A a){
        System.out.println("B 1");
    }
    public void print(B b){
        System.out.println("B 2");
    }
}
```

And with method overloading, [the method with the most specific possible arguments is chosen.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)  In this case, that is `print(B)`. Because of polymorphism, or dynamic binding, `C`'s  `print(B)` will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It chooses the second function, because its closest inheritance to the object you are providing to.

It cannot choose option C 3, because, there is no method for C 3 in reference inst.

If you pass object of A in inst.print, it will show you C 1, for rest it will show C 2.